# Hide/Remove a child view in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin

I added a UITabBarController to a view via the AddChildViewController method. I then navigate onto the next view and my tab bar appears, hey presto. As I'm in a new view now though, how can I remove the UITabBarController for the child view, as when I use the RemoveFromSuperview function it only removes the parent view and the bar still appears if I push another view.

View where child view is added:

```
tabController = new UITabBarController ();

tabController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
    vc1,
    vc2,
    vc3
};
tabController.ViewControllers [0].TabBarItem.Title = "vc1";
tabController.ViewControllers [1].TabBarItem.Title = "vc2";
tabController.ViewControllers [2].TabBarItem.Title = "vc3";

this.NavigationController.AddChildViewController(tabController);
this.NavigationController.Add(tabController.View);
```

Much Appreciated!

EDIT - A bit more detail on my problem here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6473/hide-tabbarcontroller-when-added-as-a-child-view#latest

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your initial ViewController to be a TabViewController and when a user selects something in one of the ViewControllers it transitions to a ViewController without the TabView buttons at the bottom.

If so, here's what you need to do.

In AppDelegate.cs you need to setup the window/view controllers like so:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    rootController = new UINavigationController ();
    window.RootViewController = rootController;

    var tabController = new UITabBarController ();

    var vc1 = new TestController1();
    var vc2 = new TestController2();
    var vc3 = new TestController3();

    tabController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
        vc1,
        vc2,
        vc3
    };

    tabController.ViewControllers [0].TabBarItem.Title = "vc1";
    tabController.ViewControllers [1].TabBarItem.Title = "vc2";
    tabController.ViewControllers [2].TabBarItem.Title = "vc3";

    this.rootController.PushViewController(tabController, false);

    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

Once you have this setup, you can transition to a new view like so from within the class for TestController1:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    button.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 10, 200, 30);
    button.SetTitle ("Go Child Controller", UIControlState.Normal);

    button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        NavigationController.PushViewController(new TestController4(), true);
    };

    View.AddSubview (button);
 }
```

Also, you can simplify setting the tab button titles.

Instead of doing this:

```
tabController.ViewControllers [0].TabBarItem.Title = "vc1";
```

You can just set the title from within your child UIViewController:

```
public class TestController1:UIViewController
{
    public TestController1 ()
    {
        this.Title = "vc1";
    }

   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the Finished Launching method is used at app launch, my tab view isn't used until the third screen in the app (assume a login, pin code and then summary screen with the tabbed view). Is it still possible to call the tabbed view from within the third view in the app? I want the tab view controller to be hidden when the user logs out. Thanks